# How to instance objects and set random vertex color for vertex group of the instance with geomtery nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertices, instances

I will need to help to undestand how can i skatter some default object and change randomly the vertex colour of the instances. But not for entire object but for just vertex group.

On below picture is an example what i mean. I have a cube with coloured just top face with green vertex color. I have set vertex group with just 4 top vertice and I need to create instances of this cube and change randomly the vertex color of the top face from the colour ramp colours (blue, green, red and purple). I tried something with "Store Named attribute " node but im not able to find out how to tell blender to color just top face.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply switch the domain to *"Instance"*:

[image]

And in the Shader switch the *Attribute* node from *Geometry* mode to *Instancer*.

Requires B3.4+

Answer (score 0):

Yes but there should be obviously done much more as all cubes vertices are coloured with mixture of the colors from colour ramp but i need just the top 4 vertices in vertex group will be coloured with one colour per object. I need the result will looks similar like on the second picture. [image]

[image]